# build constraints exclude all Go files

Tags: go, webassembly

This is my first attempt to do Webassembly and I've bumped into an issue.

I'm using: 
**go version go1.14.3 linux/amd64**

The code compiles properly with:

`GOARCH=wasm GOOS=js go build -o lib.wasm main.go`

When I do: **go run main.go**

I get the following error:

**main.go:8:2: build constraints exclude all Go files in /usr/local/go/src/syscall/js**

Any ideas how to solve this?

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "syscall/js"
)

var (
    listen = flag.String("listen", ":8080", "listen address")
    dir    = flag.String("dir", ".", "directory to serve")
)

func add(i []js.Value) {
    value1 := js.Global().Get("document").Call("getElementById", i[0].String()).Get("value").String()
    value2 := js.Global().Get("document").Call("getElementById", i[1].String()).Get("value").String()

    int1, _ := strconv.Atoi(value1)
    int2, _ := strconv.Atoi(value2)

    js.Global().Get("document").Call("getElementById", i[2].String()).Set("value", int1+int2)
}


func subtract(i []js.Value) {
    value1 := js.Global().Get("document").Call("getElementById", i[0].String()).Get("value").String()
    value2 := js.Global().Get("document").Call("getElementById", i[1].String()).Get("value").String()

    int1, _ := strconv.Atoi(value1)
    int2, _ := strconv.Atoi(value2)

    js.Global().Get("document").Call("getElementById", i[2].String()).Set("value", int1-int2)
}

func registerCallbacks() {
    js.Global().Set("add", new(func()))
    js.Global().Set("subtract", new(func()))
    //js.Global().Set("subtract", js.NewCallback(subtract))

    //cannot use add (type func([]js.Value)) as type func(js.Value, []js.Value) interface {} in argument to js.FuncOf
    //js.Global().Set("add", js.FuncOf(add))
    //js.Global().Set("subtract", js.FuncOf(subtract))
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    log.Printf("listening on %q...", *listen)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*listen, http.FileServer(http.Dir(*dir))))
    c := make(chan struct{}, 0)

    println("WASM Go Initialized")
    // register functions
    registerCallbacks()
    <-c
}
```

Comment: Don't use `go run`. (Why do you *want* to use `go run`?)

Comment: This `go run main.go` does more harm than it does good. It looks innocent but isn't

Comment: As the accepted answer below pointed out, there is a way to get 'GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go run main.go' to work. Use a tool like wasmbrowsertest to put a go_js_wasm_exec binary in the PATH and 'go run' and 'go test' will pick it up and use it to pass the wasm file to chromedp. Makes getting a test result feel instantaneous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `go run` with `GOARCH=wasm`; `go run` executes the built binary and because it is not OS native binary but `wasm` it will end up with operating system not understanding format of it.

Instructions how to execute WebAssembly binaries both directly using `wasm_exec.js` shim directly and Node.js are written down on [WebAssembly wiki page of golang/go repository](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WebAssembly).

To run tests in browser there is nice Golang package [agnivade/wasmbrowsertest](https://github.com/agnivade/wasmbrowsertest).

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the wasmbrowsertest. It is super useful. After following its install instructions, 'GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go run main.go' did work - because it uses a trick of 'go run' to find an executable that matches the name go_js_wasm_exec to pass the wasm to chromedp. Seems like magic until one has read a little bit about it.